# Consider reverting newly wordpress alias tag wordpress-plugin

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Yesterday the tag [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) has become an alias of [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress).  In Wordpress word, Themes and Plugins are modular add-ons that are extending the first use of this one. A theme or a plugin can drastically change it, for example [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) open e-commerce word to Wordpress.

> Also in **Wordpress Development** (StackExchange) the 2nd most used tag is **plugins**.

So this is a non sense for me.

Why?

Because:

1. When people were asking questions related to [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), it was **very useful** to use this tag when there was an additional plugin involved in the question…
2. In that logic:

   - We could make aliases of all related wordpress plugins tags like [woocomerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocomerce), [advanced-custom-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advanced-custom-fields), [wpml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpml), [revslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revslider) …
   - [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) an alias of [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) because is coded in  [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).
   - All tags containing "plugin" could be aliases of others parent tags, for example [jquery-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-plugin) could be an alias of [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).
3. On **Wordpress StackExchange** (Wordpress Development), when you submit a question and if a **Wordpress plugin** is involved in that question, most of the time it's put **on Hold** for **Off Topic** reasons. So Wordpress plugins are considered as something external. Most of the time, this questions are coming on StackOverFlow. For that reason is important also to have the possibility to tag those questions with [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin).
4. Another case is [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) that is already a plugin of [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and has also it self a bunch of dedicated plugins… For relateg questions to WooCommerce, when a plugin was involved, it was useful to have [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) too.
5. For SEO, in my opinion, is better to have [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) as a self tag…

I suppose that the only alternative is to use generic tag as [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugins).

So please just think about it, helping me to recover this useful [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) tag.

> Thinking further, It will be useful **to restrict** this kind of actions, maybe the **final decision**, to the **top users of related tags**.

Comment: Re 3.) if something is off-topic on Wordpress.SE, under what circumstances would it then be *on* topic on SO?

Comment: Can you show a question where `wordpress-plugin` would be a valid, beneficial use, helping categorize the question in a way `wordpress` alone can't?

Comment: @Pekka For example most of all related questions concerning woocommerce are off topic on Wordpress.SE, but not in SO. In general all Wordpress related topics where a plugin is involved are off topic in Wordpress.SE and come to SO (as they are redirected by hi rep users on Wordpress.SE to SO). Logically pure wordpress questions, should be on Wordpress.SE and all the others in SO…

Comment: OK, but does that mean the tag `wordpress-plugin` needs to exist? What value does it add to the question? Remember, Tags are for categorization and finding stuff later. I'm not convinced there's meaningful searches for `wordpress-plugin` that aren't as well served by `wordpress`

Comment: @Pekka Yes why not? In that case (logic) we could also merge **wordpress** as an alias of **PHP** or **CMS**. Tags diversity are important, like terms in a dictionary, of course there is synonyms and homonyms… Wordpress is one thing, and plugins and themes are an other thing, they are modular add ons (free or commercial) that are real extending the first use of wordpress… A plugin can also be like an additional app inside it... Well I stop speaking, because it will not change anything, apparently.

Comment: Tag diversity is important *when it is likely that meaningful searches will be made for that tag*. `Wordpress` needs to be separated from `PHP` because it has its own infrastructure and API. `wordpress-plugin`, arguably, does not. To me, it feels like a meta tag like `program` or `script`. I can not envision a use case where you'd meaningfully want to search for `wordpress-plugin` and `wordpress` alone wouldn't suffice. Where such a use case doesn't exist, it is counter-productive to have diverse tags. We'll simply have to agree to disagree here.

Comment: @pekka I have updated my question (at the beginning). Your point of view is respectable too… So I will delete this soon… Then I will suggest in future, to merge as alias all "plugin" related tags to their parents tags then…

Comment: No need to delete the question - Meta downvotes don't count against your reputation, and the discussion is a valid one to be had. Someone else might have the same idea. `Then I will suggest in future, to merge as alias all "plugin" related tags to their parents tags then` that would probably make sense in a *lot* of tags. Personally, I'd leave it up to the respective communities to make the decision, though.

Comment: @pekka Ok then, and what about the end of my question? Did i add another question with this in [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: It's probably best to make that a separate feature request, yes!

Comment: @Pekka What do you think about it (quickly… thanks)?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how the process works currently. My understanding had always been that that's how it's already done, if not by law then by practice. But I can be wrong. It certainly sounds like a good idea

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Note that: *Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms[...] Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4[...]* so there's already a process in place to restrict such action. However, to remove the syn. requires a moderator - but we'll be expecting a community consensus to do so...

Comment: @JonClements It will be also a security that users who vote had also score of 5+ (or more) on the children tags and not just in parent tags. And, this is what I am pointing in my question, It will be much better if the final decision was made by top users parent and children tags. Just a little like User that have gold tags, can mark a related question as duplicate… I will certainly ask a feature request around this, soon.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec don't forget that a syn. doesn't have to be an existing tag and that syn's are hard enough to get approved already so further restricting the criteria will just make it more of a hurdle to push through.

Comment: @JonClements And what about if N°1 [brasofilo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1287812/brasofilo) of wordpress tag *(the only one that have the gold tag)* ask to revert this? What would happen then? *After that I stop :)*

Comment: @LoicTheAztec if the active wordpress community thinks it's helpful to have the synonym removed - that's fine... :) I don't know enough either way to form an opinion...